# Why do I get "AttributeName cannot be empty" when making a DynamoDB table using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create two DynamoDB tables. Both tables have just one partition key, and one has a GSI with a partition key and a sort key. When I try and create the stack in CF, I receive an error on both tables stating that "Property AttributeName cannot be empty.". However, I believe I have provided AttributeName for each of my key values. I have converted the template to JSON as well, yet I get the same error. Where am I going wrong? Please note that this is not the complete template, only the part that is causing an error. Thanks very much in advance!

YAML config:

```
DynamoDBTable:
        Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        Properties:
            AttributeDefinitions: 
              - 
                AttributeName: "eventName"
                AttributeType: "S"
            TableName: "BlockCursorTable"
            Tags: 
              - 
                Key: "project"
                Value: "flow-event-monitor"
            KeySchema: 
              - 
                AttributeName: "eventName"
                KeyType: "HASH"
            ProvisionedThroughput: 
                ReadCapacityUnits: 1
                WriteCapacityUnits: 1
            TimeToLiveSpecification: 
                Enabled: false

    DynamoDBTable2:
        Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        Properties:
            AttributeDefinitions: 
              - 
                AttributeName: "listingResourceID"
                AttributeType: "N"
              - 
                AttributeName: "staticKey"
                AttributeType: "N"
              - 
                AttributeName: "timestamp"
                AttributeType: "S"
            TableName: "ListingTable"
            Tags: 
              - 
                Key: "project"
                Value: "flow-event-monitor"
            KeySchema: 
              - 
                AttributeName: "listingResourceID"
                KeyType: "HASH"
            ProvisionedThroughput: 
                ReadCapacityUnits: 1
                WriteCapacityUnits: 1
            GlobalSecondaryIndexes: 
              - 
                IndexName: "staticKey-timestamp-index"
                KeySchema: 
                  - 
                    AttributeName: "staticKey"
                    KeyType: "HASH"
                  - 
                    AttributeName: "timestamp"
                    KeyType: "RANGE"
                Projection: 
                    ProjectionType: "ALL"
                ProvisionedThroughput: 
                    ReadCapacityUnits: 1
                    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
            TimeToLiveSpecification: 
                Enabled: false
```

Equivalent JSON template:

```
{
  "DynamoDBTable": {
    "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties": {
      "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "eventName",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        }
      ],
      "TableName": "BlockCursorTable",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "project",
          "Value": "flow-event-monitor"
        }
      ],
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "eventName",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
      ],
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      },
      "TimeToLiveSpecification": {
        "Enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "DynamoDBTable2": {
    "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties": {
      "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "listingResourceID",
          "AttributeType": "N"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "staticKey",
          "AttributeType": "N"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "timestamp",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        }
      ],
      "TableName": "ListingTable",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "project",
          "Value": "flow-event-monitor"
        }
      ],
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "listingResourceID",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
      ],
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      },
      "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
          "IndexName": "staticKey-timestamp-index",
          "KeySchema": [
            {
              "AttributeName": "staticKey",
              "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
              "AttributeName": "timestamp",
              "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
          ],
          "Projection": {
            "ProjectionType": "ALL"
          },
          "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "TimeToLiveSpecification": {
        "Enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that the **exact** formatting of your YAML with those indents?

Comment: Yes do you think it would be an issue? As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't be so long as you are consistent? I have also converted it to JSON and I see the same error...

Comment: Can you please share the JSON instead which yields the same error? It can help eliminate syntax issues etc.

Comment: Added for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're specifying a `TimeToLiveSpecification` with no `AttributeName` for both tables, which is [required per AWS docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-timetolivespecification.html)**

The reason why the `Enabled` property exists, is actually for when you need to update the `AttributeName` for an *already enabled TTL* - in that case, the `Enabled` field is used to first disable the TTL to then allow you to change the `AttributeName` at the same time you re-enable TTL.

In your case, you want TTL disabled.

**Time to Live is disabled by default, so feel free to remove those sections from your CloudFormation template as they take no effect.**

I’ve included a [`Resources`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html) section below to allow you to test (considering you’ve only shared a part of your template).

This should work:

```json
{
  "Resources":{
    "DynamoDBTable":{
      "Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties":{
        "AttributeDefinitions":[
          {
            "AttributeName":"eventName",
            "AttributeType":"S"
          }
        ],
        "TableName":"BlockCursorTable",
        "Tags":[
          {
            "Key":"project",
            "Value":"flow-event-monitor"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema":[
          {
            "AttributeName":"eventName",
            "KeyType":"HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput":{
          "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
          "WriteCapacityUnits":1
        }
      }
    },
    "DynamoDBTable2":{
      "Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties":{
        "AttributeDefinitions":[
          {
            "AttributeName":"listingResourceID",
            "AttributeType":"N"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName":"staticKey",
            "AttributeType":"N"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName":"timestamp",
            "AttributeType":"S"
          }
        ],
        "TableName":"ListingTable",
        "Tags":[
          {
            "Key":"project",
            "Value":"flow-event-monitor"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema":[
          {
            "AttributeName":"listingResourceID",
            "KeyType":"HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput":{
          "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
          "WriteCapacityUnits":1
        },
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes":[
          {
            "IndexName":"staticKey-timestamp-index",
            "KeySchema":[
              {
                "AttributeName":"staticKey",
                "KeyType":"HASH"
              },
              {
                "AttributeName":"timestamp",
                "KeyType":"RANGE"
              }
            ],
            "Projection":{
              "ProjectionType":"ALL"
            },
            "ProvisionedThroughput":{
              "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
              "WriteCapacityUnits":1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```